# Char array to hex equivalent for Japanese characters

Tags: c, hex

Any one knows how can I get hex of the Japanese char array in C programming,
Any libraries or functions are fine.

suppose my string is `"ｱｲｺﾝ"`

Its hex equivalent would be, `EFBDB1EFBDB2EFBDBAEFBE9D`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just look at the array? I don't get the question. Note that questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, etc are off topic.

Comment: A string is just a (wide) character array. Is your question how to print out an individual array element in hexadecimal representation? In order to print the first element of the array in hexadecimal representation, you can simply write `printf( "%02X", string[0] );` If you want to print out all elements of the array, you will need to call `printf` in a loop.

Comment: That string seems to be encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). You may want to read this: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Actually I have to use hex value of the string in some other function.

Comment: @AlokRanjanSwain: Then you can instead use `sprintf` instead of `printf` to print the hexadecimal representation as a string into a memory buffer. You can then pass that memory buffer to the other function.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for your reply. I am new to C. If possible can you share some codes for referencing. The actual task is like creating some function which takes in Japanese char and return their hex equivalent.

Comment: @AlokRanjanSwain: What exactly do you mean by "takes in"? Do you already have the Japanese string in memory as a UTF-8 string? Or are you also talking about how to input a Japanese string from the keyboard? If you are, then the answer depends on the platform (operating system and compiler) that you are using, because ISO C itself does not directly support UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah the Japanese string is in the memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236433/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-alok-ranjan-swain).

Comment: It's probably also important to realize that, looked at another way, "the hex" would be `ff71 ff72 ff7a ff9d`.  Those are the hexadecimal representations of the four distinct code points, *after* decoding from UTF-8.  (That is, the first code point is U+FF71 Halfwidth Katakana Letter A, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the information that you provided in the question, it seems that your string is encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Printing the contents of a null-terminated character array in hexadecimal representation is simple:

```
void print_string_as_hex( const char *str )
{
    while ( *str != '\0' )
    {
        printf( "%02X", (unsigned char)*str );
        str++;
    }
}
```

Since the UTF-8 format is designed in such a way that there will never encode any bytes with the value `0`, you don't need to be aware of the details of the UTF-8 encoding. You can simply assume that when you encounter a byte with the value `0` that it must be the terminating null character of the string. Therefore, you can treat the array the same way as if it contained a fixed-length single-byte character encoding.

Although you didn't mention this in the question, in the comments section, you mentioned that you didn't want to print out the result, but instead wanted to write the hexadecimal representation to a string, so that you can pass it to another function. That is also easy:

```
void write_string_as_hex( const char *str, char *hex )
{
    while ( *str != '\0' )
    {
        sprintf( hex, "%02X", (unsigned char)*str );
        str += 1;
        hex += 2;
    }
}
```

However, that function is somewhat dangerous, as you must ensure that the buffer `hex` is large enough to contain the output, otherwise a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) will occur.

Therefore, a safe version of the function would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//this function will return true on success, false on failure
bool write_string_as_hex( const char *str, char *hex, size_t hex_size )
{
    size_t remaining = hex_size;

    while ( *str != '\0' )
    {
        //check if buffer size exceeded
        if ( remaining < 3 )
            return false;

        //convert and verify that exactly 2 characters were written
        if ( snprintf( hex, 3, "%02X", (unsigned char)*str ) != 2 )
            return false;

        //advance both pointers
        str += 1;
        hex += 2;

        //update remaining buffer size
        remaining -= 2;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just one more question. The code is working perfectly fine on online GDB compiler, However I am receiving different hex values in my visual studio 19 [`hex string:  B1B2BADD for ｱｲｺﾝ`]. Do I need to change some setting there.

Comment: Seems like the strlen() for the string is 4 in visual code and 18 in online compiler.

Comment: @AlokRanjanSwain: I guess that the problem is not in my code, but rather in the way you are defining the string literal. Please show me your code (for example by posting it in [our chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236433/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-alok-ranjan-swain)).